# Slideshow/Changing background image

Tags: html, css, url, background

I'm trying to set my page background image to be a slideshow of multiple images but I can't figure out a way to change the url of the image at a given interval while also using a fade in/out transition.

```
html {
background: url("mare.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can update your DOM with JS script

For example you can update your body tag with this script :

```
<script>
  document.body.style.background = "url("mare.jpg") no-repeat center center 
</script>
```